# How to execute just a specific block of PHP code

Tags: php, button

Assuming a PHP code like bolow

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['submit'])) {

BLOCK A

BLOCK B

}
?> 
<!html<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<body>
 <form method="get" action="#">
   <input type="submit" name="return" value="submit">
   <input type="button" value="Click"> 
 </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Is it possible to run just BLOCK A, or BLOCK B by clicking button? and not to refresh the current content of the page.

Comment: With javascript not PHP.

Comment: The form would need to contain some value which the user can indicate what should happen. Or you could have two different buttons, maybe. Your PHP can then use an if statement to decide which block of code to run. On what basis are you wanting to decide which block should be executed? Your description was rather brief and it wasn't 100% clear what the intention is

Answer (score 0):

**You can't.** PHP is a **Server**Side language, with emphasis on Server.
PHP is interpreted by a 3rd party library on the server. Then final result is sent as a text to the client.

You have two options: (to avoid refresh)

1. Dynamic part can be loaded later on with JS, via AJAX request
2. Send both results to the client, then show what you need.

Imagine you order a drink, you can't just say any drink to the waiter and expect it to turn what you desire. Each requires a different type of request, the waiter needs to go to the kitchen and bring what you need. You may order 2 drinks then drink what you want. But wouldn't make any sense because you would pay for both.